# kraken cURL REST API cannot send order saying invalid arguments

Tags: rest, curl, http-post, libcurl, gitkraken

I am able to call private user API through code like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "API-Key: mykey" -H "API-Sign: mysign" -d "nonce=123" https://api.kraken.com/0/private/Balance
```

feedback is telling me how much USD and ETH i have left in my account.

but when I switch to this trying to send order:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "API-Key: mykey" -H "API-Sign: mysign" -d "nonce=123" 'https://api.kraken.com/0/private/AddOrder?pair=XXBTZUSD&type=buy&ordertype=market&volume=0.01'
```

it says {"error":["EGeneral:Invalid arguments"]}, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to set the Content-Type header to whatever it is. In this case `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Bit odd that it's not in the docs.